# Adding columns to a pandas.DataFrame with previous row values before calling apply()

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add a new column to a `pandas` `dataframe`, where the value is calculated from the value of a column **in the previous row**.

Coming from a non-functional background (`C#`), I am trying to avoid loops since I read it is an anti-pattern.

My plan is to use `series.shift` to add a new column to the `dataframe` for the previous value, call `dataframe.apply` and finally remove the additional column. E.g.:

```
def my_function(row):
  # perform complex calculations with row.time, row.time_previous and other values
  # return the result

df["time_previous"] = df.time.shift(1)
df.apply(my_function, axis = 1)
df.drop("time.previous", axis=1)
```

In reality, I need to create four additional columns like this. Is there a better alternative to accomplish this without a loop? Is this a good idea at all?

Comment: `apply` is basically a for loop, so it's always good to avoid `apply` too ! ;) . Since you have to columns `time` and `time_previous`, just sum them : `df['time'] + df['time_previous']`

Comment: If you want the difference between rows of a column, simply use: `df["time_diff"] = df["time"].diff()`. See `pandas.Series.diff` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)

Comment: `df['time'] + df['time'].shift()`?

Comment: I apologize - I gave a very simple example. In reality, I need to perform more complex operations than a subtraction. I will update the question accordingly.